# Twisted application ignoring a certain UNIX signal - is it possible?

Tags: python, unix, signals, posix, twisted

Let's say we have the following situation:

`kill <pid>` sends `SIGTERM`

`kill -<SIGNAL> <pid>` sends `<SIGNAL>`

Sometimes, during development, I need to kill my application and restart it, at the moment - using the first type of command. But, if I have a production console opened, I have a chance to kill our production (let's say, I've forgotten about it - **THIS HAPPENED RIGHT NOW**).

The solution that came into my mind is based on ignoring `SIGTERM` in production mode, but killing the app gracefully in development mode. This way, if, for some reason, I want to kill our prod, I'll need to specify a `SIGNAL` to do it, and it'll be impossible to be done accidentally.

The app is built on Twisted.

Twisted has a number useful of methods to use signals with it - for example:

```
reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', shutdown_callback)
```

But is it possible to make it ignore a certain signal? I need only one, and I don't want to go this [`reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)`] way (some people say that it doesn't even work) - it'll require me to rewrite the whole signal handling by myself, and that's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to anything else, maybe change your production management workflow so you don't have terminals lying around where you (or someone else!) might type nasty commands - on purpose or by accident.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone You know... This would be great, but rewriting the whole architecture of the software is certainly not the topic under consideration  But I'd love to do that, agreed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done in the end (using `twistd` module with `startReactor()` override):

```
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    if signum == signal.SIGTERM:
        if is_prod():
            log.critical("Received SIGTERM on PRODUCTION call system, ignoring!")
        else:
            log.critical("Received SIGTERM on DEV call system, shutting down!")
            reactor.stop()
    elif any([
        signum == signal.SIGQUIT,
        signum == signal.SIGINT,
        signum == signal.SIGILL,
        signum == signal.SIGFPE,
        signum == signal.SIGABRT,
        signum == signal.SIGBUS,
        signum == signal.SIGPIPE,
        signum == signal.SIGSYS,
        signum == signal.SIGSEGV,
        signum == signal.SIGHUP
    ]):
        log.critical(f"*Received {signal.Signals(signum).name}, shutting down.*")
        reactor.stop()

def register_signals():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGILL, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGFPE, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGBUS, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGSYS, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal_handler)

# ...

class ApplicationRunner(twistd._SomeApplicationRunner):
    def startReactor(self, reactor, oldstdout, oldstderr):
        self._exitSignal = None
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        try:
            reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)
        except BaseException:
            close = False
            if self.config["nodaemon"]:
                file = oldstdout
            else:
                file = open("TWISTD-CRASH.log", "a")
                close = True
            try:
                traceback.print_exc(file=file)
                file.flush()
            finally:
                if close:
                    file.close()

    def createOrGetApplication(self):
        return application

    def run(self):
        self.preApplication()
        self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
        self.postApplication()


register_signals()

twistd._SomeApplicationRunner = ApplicationRunner
twistd.run()
```

Basically, this code gets access to the execution of the inner reactor, adds the required parameter, and takes all signal handling on itself. Not the best solution, but that's all we have now.

**Known bug:**
OS kills processes with SIGTERM during the restart, so if the OS triggers the process shutdown, it will send SIGTERM there, and then OS will hang. The solution is to check the following before denying the SIGTERM request:

- Existing SSH connections (if there are no connections, no user could make such a mistake, so the process shutdown should proceed).
- Bash history for `shutdown`, `reboot`, `poweroff`, and other stuff like that (Poweruser wants to shut down the server, so we should proceed with the process shut down)
- Any other system-specific conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Twisted installs some signal handlers by default but the only one it really tightly integrates with is SIGCHLD on POSIX so that it can do child process management correctly.

You can just use the Python `signal` module to change the signal-handling behavior of any signal you want (even SIGCHLD, just be aware this will probably break `reactor.spawnProcess`).

Twisted itself doesn't provide any APIs for customizing signal handling behavior.

Comment: signal.signal() calls are ignored because Twisted removes these handlers without `installSignalHandlers=False`, so this is sort of a pain to deal with.

Comment: They're not ignored.  It's just that the last call wins.  You can make your calls last with something like `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('after', 'startup', install_your_handlers)` (significantly less fragile fiddling than the code in your answer).